# Adjustpan not working properly in Samsung Tab

Tags: android

I have an expandable list view and each of its child contains edit texts. When i tap on any edit text which is at the bottom of the screen, the edit text is coming above the keyboard. Once I start typing the edit text goes back to its original position (at the bottom of the screen). The focus still remains in the field but I am not able to see what I am typing.
Also when adjustResize is used, the edit text loss its focus when it comes above keyboard.